# Remove a key from INI file during installation

Tags: inno-setup

I know how to insert a key to INI file during installation - this is the way I use it:

```
[INI]
Filename: mydefine.ini; Section: "General"; Key: "Lic"; String: "9O/2Xv"
```

My question is about removing a key during **installation** (yes - I'm not talking about uninstall).

Is that possible to remove a key during installation? How to?

I'd prefer to remove the key (rather than leaving it as an empty text).

The context:
We use some internal unit-testing during development and I turn them on if a key does exist on the INI file. I want to make sure that the key will never be released to users, so I want to explicitly remove it during installation.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way, at this time, is using scripting code. To be more specific, the [`DeleteIniEntry`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_deleteinientry) function. For example, if you'd like to remove the `Key` key from the `Section` section of a certain INI file before the installation starts, you might write:

```
[Code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): string;
begin
  DeleteIniEntry('Section', 'Key', 'C:\File.ini');
end;
```

Comment: However, when reading the context, I would suggest a very strict separating of deployment files from those that are tested. They should never get mixed. During testing you should never touch files that are deployed.

Comment: Thank you. I use it for double-check that users never get this key.

Comment: Just to make sure: it removes the key but do not ask the users to confirm deletion. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, calling that function just deletes the key without any confirmation.